# Linq to SQL update multiple records in one query

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Given the code:

```
var q = db.TranslationProjectKeys.Where(c => c.ProjectID == forProject.ID);
foreach (var key in q)
{
    key.Live = false;
}
db.SubmitChanges();
```

If I run the SQL server profiler it shows dozens of `UPDATE....` SQL statements.  I believe this would be considerably faster if this query was executed with one `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE TranslationProjectKeys SET Live = 0 WHERE ProjectID = x
```

Is there a way to make the query execute in this way?

I'm wary of using `db.ExecuteCommand("...")` as I am aware the context can be cached which can cause some bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [EntityFramework.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended/) . You can execute multiple update.
For Example

```
var q = db.TranslationProjectKeys.Where(c => c.ProjectID == forProject.ID).Update(c => new TranslationProjectKey{ Live  = false })
```

Answer (score 1):

linq to sql does not have a built in mass update function (unless something has changed). you could just execute the command manually like

```
dataContext.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE TranslationProjectKeys SET Live = 0 WHERE ProjectID = {0}", x);
```

or if you wanted to get fancy, you could try implementing your own mass update functionality like [this](https://terryaney.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/batch-updates-and-deletes-with-linq-to-sql/) article shows, but it is MUCH more in depth and complicated (Though it IS possible to do)

Comment: Thanks for answer, am a bit wary of using `ExecuteCommand` due to cache state of the data context

Comment: @TomGullen Try checking into the article I linked. It seems like the batch updating is kind of a pain in butt, but it could be pretty sweet and worth it to take the time to implement it. Other than that I am not sure there are any other options, unfortunately

Comment: @TomGullen also what exactly do you mean about the cache state?